# Einstein notation • Cartesian reference frame • Cartan, theory of spinors

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, mathematical-physics, change-of-basis

I’m having a problem understanding Cartan’s notation in *theory of spinors* §2. Here are the definitions:

[image: definition of fundamental form]
[image: definitions of scalar product and scalar square]

Set x to $3 \\ 4$ so the length is 5, then set as a simple test basis $\eta_1$ to $1 \\ 1$ and $\eta_2$ to $0 \\ 1$.

$u^1$ I set to 3 and $u^2$ to 1. The scalar product of $\eta_1 . \eta_2$ is 1. If I run over the $u^i u^j$ successively and independently, that gives me $$3 \quad 3 \\ 3 \quad 1 \\ 1 \quad 3 \\ 1 \quad 1$$, which sum to 16, not 25.

If changing basis is supposed to change length, then I don’t understand why Cartan’s $$u^i u^j \eta_1 . \eta_2$$ is a good definition of fundamental form.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here... Why do you have an issue with the vector changing length under the coordinate transform?

Comment: @K.defaoite Well, you just reversed the question as I posed it. Why is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = (3, 4) = 3e_1 + 4 e_2$, with square length $3^2 + 4^2 = 25$. Now express $x$ in the new basis of $\eta_1 = (1, 1)$ and $\eta_2 = (0, 1)$, and we get that
$$ x = (3, 4) = (3, 3) + (0, 1) = 3 \eta_1 + \eta_2.$$
Therefore in the expression $x = u^i\eta_i$ we have $u^1 = 3$ and $u^2 = 1$, as you found.

Now consider the fundamental form $g_{ij} = \eta_i \cdot \eta_j$, which we can write as a matrix
$$ g = \begin{pmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Evaluating $\Phi$ we get
$$ \begin{aligned}
\Phi
  &= g_{ij} u^i u^j\\
  &= g_{11} u^1 u^1 + g_{12} u^1 u^2 + g_{21} u^2 u^1 + g_{22} u^2 u^2 \\
  &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \\
  &= 25.
\end{aligned}
$$